# How to reset the Registry Editor view back to root using VB script?

Tags: windows, registry

I am trying to automate the collapsing of all of the expanded keys and hives in the Registry Editor - hopefully using VB script (I would prefer not using AutoIt to transverse the entire registr).

How does the OS store which registry keys and hives are expanded and which are minimized, such that upon reboot, the same keys and hives are expanded and minimized as they were before? There must be a way to sort of "reset" this state.

I have to do this on Windows Vista, 2003, and 2008.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By deleting the "LastKey" which holds the last key viewed in the Registry Editor, the view returns to the root view.

```
WshShell.RegDelete "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Applets\Regedit\LastKey"
```